# Find next and preceding row from an item

Tags: postgresql

In a webapp I have a carousel of items.

```
<Prev | Item 1 | Item 2 (active) |  Item 3 | Next>
```

When a user directly accesses a page where "Item 2" should be preselected - I need the preceding item and the next item.

So the query should be something like "Give me the row before Item 2 and after Item 2 and only these two."

So given the following dummy data with an id and a boolean field if the item can be accessed by the user:

```
CREATE TABLE items (id integer, can_access boolean);

INSERT INTO items SELECT 1,true;
INSERT INTO items SELECT 2,false;
INSERT INTO items SELECT 3,true;
INSERT INTO items SELECT 5,false;
INSERT INTO items SELECT 6,true;
```

When id:3 is the active id - I want to find id:1 and id:6.

Comment: Unrelated, but: your insert statements can be simplified to a single one: `INSERT INTO items values (1,true), (2,false), (3,true), (5,false), (6,true);`

Comment: Rows in a relational database are not sorted in any way. So unless you have something you can sort by, there is no concept of "preceding" and "next" item. Is it safe to assume that your sort order for "preceding" and "next" is defined by the `id` column?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - yes correct. Sorry - the id is the sort criterion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using windowing functions to get the relative navigation for all pages, your query will look like this:

```
SELECT
    lag("id") over w AS prev,
    id,
    lead("id") over w AS next
FROM items
WHERE can_access = true
WINDOW w as (order by id)
```

giving you these results:

```
prev    active    next
-----------------------
NULL    1         3
1       3         6
3       6         NULL
```

To only return the navigation for 3, you can use an intermediate CTE:

```
WITH 
    navi(prev, active, "next") AS
    (
        SELECT
            lag("id") over w AS prev,
            id,
            lead("id") over w AS next
        FROM items
        WHERE can_access = true
        WINDOW w as (order by id) 
    )
SELECT * FROM navi WHERE active = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to use `id` to define the order of rows:

```
(
    select *
    from items
    where can_access and id > 3
    order by id
    limit 1
)
union
(
    select *
    from items
    where can_access and id < 3
    order by id desc
    limit 1
)
```

Alternative solutions may use window functions or self join, usually the simple above query is faster.

Comment: Although there's no indication in the results of which row is previous, and which row is next (you could add a column to indicate this). If there's not an applicable next or previous page, you'd have to ascertain this by examining the row count.